# Como posso fazer para detectar a visibilidade de um elemento (sem jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer para saber se um determinado elemento não está visível com Javascript puro?

Eu sei fazer isso com jQuery, que é assim:

```
 $('.btn').click(function () {
      $('#box').is(':visible') ? $('#box').hide() : $('#box').show();
 });
```

Mas e em Javascript puro? Qual é o meio mais eficiente de saber se um elemento no DOM está visível ou não?

Comment: Qual é o problema com a pergunta? Poderia explicar?

Comment: aparentemente é o `if(user == 4995) downvote();`

Comment: R: Use jQuery :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discordo da outra resposta, `style.display` é apenas para propriedades inline, pra isto você terá que usar `getComputedStyle`, `currentStyle`, o atributo `type="hidden"` no elemento `<input>`.

Com `getComputedStyle` (e `currentStyle`) conseguimos verificar as propriedade `visibility` e `display`, tanto no atributo `style=""` quanto na tag `<style>`, quanto em propriedades dentro de arquivos CSS que estejam afetando elementos na atual página.

```js
function getStyle(elem, prop)
{
    if (elem.currentStyle) { //IE8

        //Converte hifens para camelCase
        prop = prop.replace(/-([a-z])/gi, function (value) {
            return value.toLowerCase();
        });
        
        return elem.currentStyle[prop];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {//Navegadores modernos


        //Converte camelCase para hifens
        prop = prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
        
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
}

function isVisible(elem)
{
    //Verifica inputs
    if (/^(input|select|textarea)$/i.test(elem.nodeName) && elem.type === "hidden") {
        return false;
    }

    //Verifica a propriedade visibility
    if (getStyle(elem, "visibility") === "hidden") {
        return false;
    }

    //Verifica a propriedade display
    if (getStyle(elem, "display") === "none") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function isHidden(elem)
{
     return !isVisible(elem);
}
```

```css
#ELEMENTO_1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#ELEMENTO_3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ELEMENTO_1">Invisivel visibility: hidden</div>
<button onclick="console.log(isVisible(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_1')));">Testar visibility: hide</button>
<hr>

<div id="ELEMENTO_2">Visivel</div>
<button onclick="console.log(isVisible(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_2')));">Testar Visivel</button>
<hr>

<div id="ELEMENTO_3">Invisivel display: none</div>
<button onclick="console.log(isVisible(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_3')));">Testar display: none</button>
<hr>

<input type="hidden" id="ELEMENTO_4">
<button onclick="console.log(isVisible(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_4')));">Testar input[type=hidden]</button>
```

### Exemplos:

```
var el = document.getElementById("meuId");

alert(isVisible(el)); //Retorna true se visivel, caso contrário retorna false

alert(isHidden(el)); //Retorna true se oculto, caso contrário retorna false
```

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa função, mas de qualquer forma nem sempre se usa classe CSS para esconder ou mostrar um elemento.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai isso não analisa apenas o CSS, ele analisa o atributo `style=""`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como assim?

Comment: Esquece, quero evitar debates por hoje

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Err, mas eu disse que o OP poderia usar aquela condição caso ele esteja mudando a visibilidade do elemento só com o `display`, pois eu não sabia de outras maneiras. Mas eu sei que é mais correto usar essa função citada na sua resposta.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai Estou quase entendendo, mas ainda esta um pouco dificil pra mim, se refere a setar via javascript: `element.style.display="none";`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Exactly.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai mas foi o que eu disse, o `currentStyle` e o `getComputedStyle` reconhecem o `style.display="none"`, pois a leitura deles é partir do que esta "renderizado" e não do que esta no arquivo CSS :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, eu sei. Minha resposta só funciona com `display` definido em qualquer `CSS` inline.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai vixe foi mal, eu nem vi que a resposta era sua, por isso estou boiando... mas então, é muito comum as pessoas usarem o atributo `class=""` pra esconder as coisas, fazendo apenas o uso de `el.className = ""` :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Bom, o jQuery provavelmente muda o estilo em linha. Meu método só não vai funcionar com qualquer coisa fora definir o `display...:...` em linha. Vou fazer um update !

Comment: @KlaiderKlai Ahh entendi, nesse caso se usar `.hide` ou `.animate` vai ser o element.style.display mesmo, mas é muito comum em jQuery usarem também `.addClass`, a sua resposta esta certa sim para o caso do AP (esta uma otima resposta a sua ;) ), só que geralmente tentamos fazer as respostas relevantes pra toda comunidade ;) (claro que isso não é obrigatoriedade)

Answer (score 2):

Se você está mudando a visibilidade do elemento somente com a propriedade `display` (inline) do CSS, então você pode fazer essa condição para checar se o elemento é visível:

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

if(box.style.display !== "none") {
    /* Bloco */
}
```

`box.style.display !== "none"` vai retornar `true` caso o modo de exibição seja indefinido, `"initial"`, `"block"`, `"inline-block"` ou outros tipos.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o [método `window.getComputedStyle();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

`var escondido = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("element")).display === 'none';`

Este método avalia se o elemento *ou um de seus pais* está invisível.

Comment: Tá vendo, tomei negativo, mas foi bom perguntar. Esse aí eu não conhecia :D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) para isso, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script>
  function isHidden(id) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('teste');
    if (elemento.offsetParent === null) {
      elemento.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
       alert('Agora não ve mais!')
      elemento.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="teste">
  Você me ve?
</div>

<button onclick="isHidden()">
  Clica aqui!
</button>
```