# Como saber se um objeto pode ser focado

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um script para lançar erros com o javascript e nessa função ele lança o foco no campo que está com erros. Em alguns casos, quando o campo não está visível, por exemplo, é apresentado um erro no console, nada tão grave que interrompa minha aplicação, o erro fala que o campo não é focalizável. Como esses erros me deixam inquieto eu quero evita-los e por isso quero fazer uma condicional para verificar se um campo pode ser focado com o `.focus` ou não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode checar a visibilidade, como fiz nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137851/3635

```js
function getStyle(elem, prop)
{
    if (elem.currentStyle) { //IE8
        return elem.currentStyle[prop];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {//Navegadores modernos
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
}

function isVisible(elem)
{
    //Verifica inputs
    if (/^(input|select|textarea)$/i.test(elem.nodeName) && elem.type === "hidden") {
        return false;
    }

    //Verifica a propriedade visibility
    if (getStyle(elem, "visibility") === "hidden") {
        return false;
    }

    //Verifica a propriedade display
    if (getStyle(elem, "display") === "none") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function focalizar(elem)
{
     if (isVisible(elem) && elem.focus) {
         elem.focus();
         return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

```css
#ELEMENTO_1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#ELEMENTO_3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ELEMENTO_1">Invisivel visibility: hidden</textarea>
<button onclick="console.log(focalizar(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_1')));">Focar elemento invisível</button>
<hr>

<textarea id="ELEMENTO_2">Visivel</textarea>
<button onclick="console.log(focalizar(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_2')));">Focar elemento visível</button>
<hr>

<textarea id="ELEMENTO_3">Invisivel display: none</textarea>
<button onclick="console.log(focalizar(document.getElementById('ELEMENTO_3')));">Focar elemento invisível</button>
<hr>
```